# Maven Eclipse (m2e) and Nexus - Add Dependency Search Results Limited

Tags: eclipse, nexus, m2e

The default maven install with eclipse allows you to right-click on your projects and go: Maven->Add Dependency, and then from here search the central index for the artifacts you want.

However, after setting up a local nexus server (and mirroring central), and configuring maven to use it (http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html),
I am now unable to see all of the artifacts from the search.  I can only see a subset (ie. the ones that have been used/downloaded already).

I have already made sure that my nexus server is set to download remote indexes (and I can see/search these all from Nexus' web interface), but eclipse doesn't seem to be picking the index up.

help please. :)

Software:
eclipse indigo release 2.
m2e - 1.0.200.20111228-1245.
nexus 2.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...apparently patience is the answer to this magical question.
It has been a couple weeks, and it is now magically working on a couple of my dev machines.

My best guess is that eclipse may not always refresh its index every time you restart it, and that it just wasn't pulling down the latest index from our nexus server. (caching timeout? refresh timeout?)

Any confirmation of this behaviour/similar experiences with this would probably be helpful in closing out this thread. :)